# adding custom news boxes and Post Types in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to add custom **News Box** In **WordPress** like this [website](http://www.stickytuts.com/) .

I mean that I need a special box for each category, so it displays the latest posts in this category .

So how can I make this box import the posts from special category ??

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm the webmsater of http://www.stickytuts.com Sticky TUTS is a blogger hosted blog, but for wordpress there's a lot of plugins to do that here's some of them

- **wordpress.org/plugins/tags/news-bar**
- **wordpress.org/plugins/news-bar**

And here's a blog post that you can find in what you are looking for:

**www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-a-news-ticker-in-wordpress**